# Java Android - How to sort a JSONArray based on keys

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, sorting

I'm getting this string (from a webservice) into a JSONArray like this,

```
[
 {
  "lat": "-16.408545",
  "lon": "-71.539105",
  "type": "0",
  "distance": "0.54"
 },
 {
  "lat": "-16.4244317845",
  "lon": "-71.52562186",
  "type": "1",
  "distance": "1.87"
 },
 {
  "lat": "-16.4244317845",
  "lon": "-71.52562186",
  "type": "1",
  "distance": "0.22"
 }
]
```

I need to sort it by the **distance** key to show the nearest first and farthest last. I didn't try any code because I really don't have any ideas. I'm not using the GSON library, I'm using `org.json.JSONArray`.

Comment: use undercore.js library , you have various sorting solutions are with it.

Comment: please take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952230/after-sorting-jsonarray-custom-list-view-not-changed) ..same issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First parse your array in a list

```
JSONArray sortedJsonArray = new JSONArray();
List<JSONObject> jsonList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    jsonList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
}
```

then use collection.sort to sort the newly created list

```
Collections.sort( jsonList, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {

    public int compare(JSONObject a, JSONObject b) {
        String valA = new String();
        String valB = new String();

        try {
            valA = (String) a.get("distance");
            valB = (String) b.get("distance");
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            //do something
        }

        return valA.compareTo(valB);
    }
});
```

Insert the sorted values in your array

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    sortedJsonArray.put(jsonList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: plz see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952230/sorting-custom-adapter-list-item-in-custom-listview) how to sort listview by name

Comment: Thank you so much, It helps me lots of time

Comment: to switch among the order --> `valA.compareTo(valB)` vs `valB.compareTo(valA)`

Answer (score 0):

Parse your json object into a model say array-List and sort it using comparator.

```
ArrayList<ClassObject> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);     
for(Object obj : jsonArray){
   dataList.add(//your data model);
}
```

Please refer this link for sorting of array-list
http://java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/arraylist/sort-comparator/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> array = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
   try {
       array.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
   } catch (JSONException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}   

Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {

@Override
public int compare(JSONObject lhs, JSONObject rhs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        return (lhs.getDouble("distance").compareTo(rhs.getDouble("distance")));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
});
```

And after this you can convert sorted `ArrayList` `array` into `JSONArray`.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(array);
String jsonArrayStr = jsonArray.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

**In kotlin you can do as below**

> Parse your array in a list

```
val sortedJsonArray = JSONArray()
val jsonList = ArrayList<JSONObject>()
for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
    jsonList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i))
}
```

> Sort the newly created list

```
jsonList.sortWith { a, b ->
    var valA = String()
    var valB = String()
    try {
        valA = a.get("distance") as String
        valB = b.get("distance") as String
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    valA.compareTo(valB)
}
```

> Insert the sorted values in your json array

```
for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
    sortedJsonArray.put(jsonList[i])
}
```

*Thanks to @crysis for his answer.*